Help with inscription
The following is part of an inscription in the wine cellar of a private residence in Tuscany which dates back to 1573. The rest of the inscription is in Latin and easily translated but would like to know what is in the short section in these two photos .

What does the rest of the inscription say? That would certainly be helpful!

They look more like some signs, such as tally marks, than verbal expressions.

Here is rest of inscription in Latin (?) or Italian (?) along with translation:   In nome di Dio e Sante Francesco e beata (?) a dritta sta il bono vino ed io Capomastro Martin del Nero ho fatto e se io ho erato mi perdonerete 1573 AD (anno domini) 13 di marzo
"In the name of God and Saint Frances and holy (?) on the right side there is the good wine and me headmason Martin del Nero
I built and if I did a mistake please forgive me 1573 year of the lord 13th of March"
